# search path is getting updated automatically

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

In postgres 11.5 for a running session suddenly lot of errors reported in pg_logs "relation does not exist". After enabling extra logging we have found out that just before the errors the following statement is getting executed and feels same is the culprit.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)
```

We are not running it. Could anyone please help me to understand by whom and under what circumstances it is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me pull out my crystal ball and see what you did...

Ah! I see you restoring a plain format `pg_dump` from an interactive session using `\i dumpfile`, so that the settings from the dump remain active in your session after the restore is completed.

Comment: Yes we have plain text format dumps. I am confuse about \i option,  is it for psql or for pg_restore? How can I prevent this setting to be remain active in the session? I still need to check if any scheduled restore is happening.

Comment: Either say `RESET search_path;` or - simpler - disconnect and reconnect. Settings changed with `SET` only hold for the duration of a database session.

Comment: I rechecked pg_logs and found out 1.  autovacuum: processing database 2. postgres child[8760]: starting with (postgres)  3. InitPostgres 4. above mentioned query. and not seeing anything related to pg_restore or pg_dump . DO you think it can be executed by vacuum or something related ? these queries are just before the error.

Comment: similar logs in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269365/psql-connection-timeout-issues

Comment: You are confused. `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are not SQL statements, they are not run in the database. `pg_dump` produces a file that contains the statement in your question. You run that file with `\i`, so the statement shows up in your log. Nothing to worry. Just disconnect and reconnect, and you are good.

Comment: Ok that I know, I couldn't express exactly. But the thing is I want to know how it is getting executed. You told while restore it is getting executed but in pg log there is no trace of any restore. I was wondering if any other process execute it. Because before the error some queries are getting executed successfully and after success query there is no restore but one autovacuum which is making me to think in other direction.

Comment: You must have used `\i dumpfile` or something similar in your current session, like I wrote in my answer. Full disclosure: I am not clairvoyant. You should know yourself what you typed...

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code of Postgres I have found that libpqconnect is running it while making a connection. There are many places but libpqconnect is the file where pg_is_in_reovery is also running after the search path and satisfying the my criteria.